# Build error, NuGet refrence package error

Tags: android, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am getting the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on
>   this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.26.1.0.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.targets. WoWonder    D:\Compressed\wowonderandroid-162\codecanyon-19034167-wowonder-android-messenger-mobile-application-for-wowonder\Messnger_v1.6.2\WoWonder_Messenger\WoWonder.csproj 1064

Has anyone else faced this issue while trying to build a project?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow question checklist. You might also want to learn about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples

Comment: Hi Suvooh, just checking-in to see if there's any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to build a project that contains references to a missing NuGet package.

This probably means that the package is not installed in the `global-packages` folder or in the in the `packages` folder, or that the project file contains absolute paths and you have moved the project.

On [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/Consume-Packages/Package-restore-troubleshooting) Microsoft Docs page you can find a detailed explanation for this issue and different ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the tips in **Alessandra's** answer, also consider removing this script in your project file(xx.xxproj) if it exists:

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.26.1.0.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.26.1.0.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Then make sure you've made these options checked:

[image]

Run a rebuild and this issue would go away. Hope it helps:)